# Autoconnect Cisco IPSec VPN on MacOS Sierra

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco-vpn-client, sshfs, macos-sierra

MacOS' built in network settings do not allow me to save the password, and the connection dies numerous times per day.  I'm trying to find solutions for

1. Save VPN password.
2. Start VPN on login.
3. Reconnect VPN anytime connection dies.

extra credit

4. Automount remote development box over SSH with pre-shared key.

As for #4 I currently manually mount with sshfs-beta via terminal but it's very slow and has to be done everytime I login and everytime the VPN connection resets.

Very frustrating to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

**I am using this script for vpn automated reconnection**

```
on idle
set vpn_name to "'cloud.lietaer.net'"
tell application "System Events"
    set rc to do shell script "scutil --nc status " & vpn_name
    if rc starts with "Disconnected" then
        do shell script "scutil --nc start " & vpn_name
    end if
end tell
return 10
end idle
```

Point #4 try :
[transmit](https://panic.com/transmit/)